# How to validate uniqueness then suggest a unique alternative on fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, slug

I want to create slugs based on a title field, so those slugs will have to be unique.

Is there a callback method for when validates_uniqueness_of fails so that i can append a character to the end of the slug to make it unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like this would be better as a before_create callback than a validation. It's not actually invalid if the name's a dupe; you just need to uniquify it.

Comment: So i would have to check if that slug exists and then change the param in that before_create method?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use `validates_uniqueness_of`, you can always do it yourself and then customize the message. For example:

```
validate :field_uniqueness

private
def field_uniqueness
    if self.exists?(:conditions => {:username => self.username})
        errors.add(:username, :name_taken, :username => "#{self.username}1")
    end
end
```

If username is already taken, suggest the username with "1" appended to the end of it.

Comment: rather than putting a 1, would it be possible to check for a count of duplicate user and add 1. so a regex for the username ignoring the appended digits. It was for slugs too, so it's based on the title so that would remain unchanged just the slug would have the appended digit in that instance, so I think I would be able to do a count of posts with the same title.

Comment: Assuming that the same title = the same slug, you would have to count the number of titles, and then if the count is > 0 you append count + 1.